# Final Variables in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Let us consider the following code .

```
 class A {

    final int i =0 ; 
     ...........
      ....
}

   class B extends A {
             i = 10 ;
   --------

}
```

In the above code , i is declared as Final . But in the subclass B , it has been inherited and reassigned  to value 10 .

I suddenly got this thought and unfortunately unable to download javac compiler I posted this question to know whether it is possible to reassign a final variable in subclass .

So can we reassign the final variable in subclass ?

Comment: "and reassigned to value 10" - It was not reassigned, as your code does not compile. You would need to reassign it inside a method, but it's `final`, so you can't.

Comment: Primitives cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

The `final` keyword, when applied to fields of a Java `class`, has nothing to do with inheritance. Instead, it indicates that outside of the constructor, that field cannot be reassigned.

I have taken it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799018/inheritance-of-final-fields-in-java), The first answer in here will give a good explanation to your question